# Java Loops and If conditions for creating X box

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcoHs.png)How to print a big X made up of small X Box which I have provided the code below. The size of the X must be equal to the size of the small X Box.

```
System.out.print("Enter the desired cube size: "); 
int size = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

for(int row=1; row<=size; row++) {
    for(int col=1; col<=size; col++) {
        if (row == 1 || row == size || col == 1 || col == size || col == row ||col == size-(row-1)) {
            System.out.print("X ");
        }else {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output should look like this. The size of the big X must be equal to the small one. Like this, the given size is 3.

```
X X X     X X X
X   X     X   X
X X X     X X X
     X X X 
     X   X
     X X X
X X X     X X X
X   X     X   X
X X X     X X X
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: So, you provided the code. Whats the problem? Does it display something else. Does it compile?

Comment: It runs well, but I want it to print a Giant X made up of the small X Box which is on my code.

Comment: That's funny... yesterday I also had a code that *ran well* but didn't draw a giant X into my console. No, really, ... do you have any insight on where this fails?

Comment: what if the size is something else than 3?

Comment: the example which I have stated is a Big X symbol made up of X Boxes. The size will depend on the input of the user.

Comment: Please understand that "I want my code to..." is not a question, you need to ask a proper question about your code and explain whatever issue you are having with it.

Comment: So the size of the big X will be size*size?

Comment: Yes, the size must be equal.

Answer (score 3):

If I have not misunderstood you, when you insert the size keyboard you should always print five mini "x" in size -> size * size. By retouching your code, I changed the loops for(), size*3, and the line of the if..else. Where if (), if we have a square, we will divide it into 9 parts. If we are in the corners or in the center, we will print on screen "X ", if not, " ".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.print("Enter the desired cube size: "); 
    int size = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    for(int row=0; row<(size*3); row++) {
        for(int col=0; col<(size*3); col++) {
            if ((row/size!=1 && col/size!=1) || (row/size==1 && col/size==1)) {
                System.out.print("X ");
            }else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

This will return the following content:
[program exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhcSr.png)

```
 X X X       X X X 
 X X X       X X X
 X X X       X X X
       X X X 
       X X X
       X X X
 X X X       X X X
 X X X       X X X
 X X X       X X X
```

What I have not implemented is the white space in the center of the small squares. Since, if it is not fulfilled that there is a center, which one would remain blank? The case: size = 4 for example

```
 X X X X         X X X X 
 X X X X         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
         X X X X 
         X X X X
         X X X X
         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
```

If you want small Xs to have only one "X" border, you have to add the following condition to the if..else instruction:

```
for(int col=0; col<(size*3); col++) {
    if ((((row/size!=1 && col/size!=1)) || (row/size==1 && col/size==1)) && 
       (row%size==0 || col%size==0 || row%size==size-1 || col%size==size-1)) {
        System.out.print("X ");
    }else {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
}
```

Where if row or column, are in module 0 or size-1 of size, is that they are on the edge of the small X.

and the result is:

```
 X X X X         X X X X 
 X     X         X     X
 X     X         X     X
 X X X X         X X X X
         X X X X 
         X     X
         X     X
         X X X X
 X X X X         X X X X
 X     X         X     X
 X     X         X     X
 X X X X         X X X X
```

I do not know if it has been completely clear, it is my first post and I have tried to explain the best I know.

Comment: for example: if the user input is 5, then the small Xboxes must be 5 and the big X must be also made up of 5x5 small Xboxes.